# Tikzpicture looks different between tikzposter and normal document

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, scaling, tikzposter

I make a figure for a paper with `tikzpicture`, and now I want to put the same figure in a `tikzposter`. However, the figure looks different when I put it in the `tikzposter`. How can I make the behaviour consistent?

Here is the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
 \node (1) at (0,9) {\includegraphics{pics/bin-tree-lattice/01}};
  \node (2) at (-2.5,7.75) {\includegraphics{pics/bin-tree-lattice/02}};
  \node (3) at (0,7) {\includegraphics{pics/bin-tree-lattice/03}};
  \node (4) at (3,6.5) {\includegraphics{pics/bin-tree-lattice/04}};
  \node (5) at (-4,6.6) {\includegraphics{pics/bin-tree-lattice/05}};
  \node (6) at (0,4.5) {\includegraphics{pics/bin-tree-lattice/06}};
  \node (7) at (2,4.5) {\includegraphics{pics/bin-tree-lattice/07}};
  \node (8) at (-4,4.5) {\includegraphics{pics/bin-tree-lattice/08}};
  \node (9) at (-4,2.5) {\includegraphics{pics/bin-tree-lattice/09}};
  \node (10) at (-2,4.5) {\includegraphics{pics/bin-tree-lattice/10}};
  \node (11) at (3,2.5) {\includegraphics{pics/bin-tree-lattice/11}};
  \node (12) at (-2.5,1) {\includegraphics{pics/bin-tree-lattice/12}};
  \node (13) at (0,2.25) {\includegraphics{pics/bin-tree-lattice/13}};
  \node (14) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{pics/bin-tree-lattice/14}};
  \draw (1) -- (2) -- (5) -- (8) -- (9) -- (12) -- (14);
  \draw (1) -- (4) -- (11) -- (14);
  \draw (4) -- (7) -- (13) -- (14);
  \draw (1) -- (3) -- (6) -- (11);
  \draw (5) -- (10) -- (9);
  \draw (2) -- (7);
  \draw (3) -- (8);
  \draw (6) -- (12);
  \draw (10) -- (13);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is the result in a normal `article` document class:

[image: normal figure]

and here is the result when I put the exact same code in `tikzposter`:

[image: wrong figure]

Clearly, the second figure doesn't look right. Any suggestions on how to solve this? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: nodes have an inner sep whose size depends on the font size. Set it to some absolute value.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: that solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to answer this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nodes have an `inner sep` whose size depends on the *font size*. Set it to some absolute value to avoid side effects when changing the class.